# I have created an employee class and 2 new employee instances, but only the 1st employee info works

Tags: c#

I've scoured your site trying to figure out how to do this problem. I'm a newbie to c#, so I apologize if I ask a newbie question.

We've just started classes in our course, which I don't find too bothersome. However, for our first assignment I have created a class Employee that takes a percentage and figures out the pay raise for an employee. In the Main program, I create 2 new instances, e1 and e2. I use the GetValue method to read in the data for the employee. My problem is that it works great for the 1st employee, but doesn't ask for input for the 2nd employee. How can I get the program to read, and output, data for both e1 and e2?

Is there some loop or iteration I can do to get the input for both employees?

Thanks in advance,
Diane

Here's my code:

```
//identify the variables
        string firstName, lastName, employeeID, department;
        decimal salary;

        firstName = GetValue("First Name");
        lastName = GetValue("Last Name");
        employeeID = GetValue("Employee ID");
        department = GetValue("Employee Department");
        salary = Convert.ToDecimal(GetValue("Salary"));
        //create two employee objects

        Employee e1 = new Employee(firstName, lastName, employeeID, salary, department);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(firstName, lastName, employeeID, salary, department);

        //get user input

        //clear the screen
        Console.Clear();

        //Display the pay rise information

        Console.WriteLine("Total increase in salary for employee 1 is {0}", e1);

        Console.WriteLine("Total increase in salary for employee 2 is {0}", e2);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }//end of Main


    static public string GetValue(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the {0} >>", value);
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        return input;

    }//end GetValue
```

Comment: You are providing the exact same values for both `Employee`s - you are not asking for new or different input for the second `Employee`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just need to wrap the information-gathering part in a loop. Here's a quick example. In the example below, I'm also adding the employee objects to a list so we don't have to maintain separate individual references to them.

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();

// Populate our list with two employees
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var firstName = GetValue("First Name");
    var lastName = GetValue("Last Name");
    var employeeID = GetValue("Employee ID");
    var department = GetValue("Employee Department");
    var salary = Convert.ToDecimal(GetValue("Salary"));

    employees.Add(new Employee(firstName, lastName, employeeID, salary, department));
}

// Display the employee information:

var counter = 1;
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Total increase in salary for employee {0} is {1}",
        counter++, employee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the employee is a candidate for a separate method in this scenario.

Specifically, this code should be invoked twice:

```
string firstName, lastName, employeeID, department;
decimal salary;

firstName = GetValue("First Name");
lastName = GetValue("Last Name");
employeeID = GetValue("Employee ID");
department = GetValue("Employee Department");
salary = Convert.ToDecimal(GetValue("Salary"));

Employee e1 = new Employee(firstName, lastName, employeeID, salary, department);
```

You could create a method such as:

```
static Employee ReadEmployeeFromInput()
{
    //... all the code from the above snippet;
    return e1;
}
```

Then, in your main method, read two employees:

```
Employee e1 = ReadEmployeeFromInput();
Employee e2 = ReadEmployeeFromInput();
```

That could be repeated/ expanded from there to take more employees, in a loop, etc.